# my string index is out of range in this cipher code

Tags: python

```
def cipherText():
    text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    key = int(input("Enter numerical key--"))
    word = str(input("Type word to be ciphered--"))
    i = 0
    k = 0
    n = len(word)
    print(n)
    while n >= 0:
        letter = word[i]
        i = i + 1
        while k <= 25:
            textLetter = text[k]
            if textLetter == letter:
                givenLetter = letter
                if k < (25 - key):
                    cipherLength = k + key
                else:
                    cipherLength = k + key - 25
                print(text[cipherLength])
            k = k + 1
        n = n - 1


cipherText()
```

WHEN I RUN THIS FOLLOWING MESSAGE POPS OUT:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 23, in
>   
>       cipherText()   File "main.py", line 10, in cipherText
>       letter=word[i] IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: `n` starts at `len(word)` and goes to zero. `i` starts a zero and goes to `len(word)`. When `n` is zero (the last iteration of your loop), `i` is `len(word)`, which is after the end of your string. Perhaps you mean `while n > 0:`, or since you're not using `n` for anything, just use `for letter in word`.

Comment: TLDR: Why are you not just using `for letter in word` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify condition `while n>=0:`, as list starts with `0th` index.

this line,

```
while n>=0:
```

should be,

```
while n-1>=0:
```